# Private variables and Access modifiers

Tags: java, access-modifiers

If the variable has access modifier "private" which restricts it from getting accessed by other class. Why set public getter methods to access it that private variable? Wouldn't it just be much better to set it to a public variable?. I'm confused. Can someone please explain this. Thank you.

Comment: if you have a `getter` you can `read` it, if you add a `setter` you can write to it, if you make it `public` you do not have this control.

Comment: @Lorenz As you are new to stackoverflow first of all see the guidelines before posting any question here

Comment: I'm just starting to learn java. So please forgive me for asking this kind this question.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar, Ok thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thanks @ScaryWombat.